# Passing an object and changing the object vs changing its properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, pass-by-reference

Its my understanding that JavaScript objects are passed by reference (or passed by value, where the value is the memory address of the object). Why is it that when I change the entire object that is being passed into a function, my changes are not reflected inside the global window object?

But when I change the properties of an object passed into a function, the object is updated?

```
// Case 1
var objectX = {name: 'stackoverflow'};

function changeProperty(objectX) {
   objectX.name = 'google';
}

changeProperty(objectX);
console.log(objectX); // {name: 'google'};

// Case 2
var objectY = {name: 'stackoverflow'};

function changeEntireObj(objectY) {
   objectY = {};
}

changeEntireObj(objectY);
console.log(objectY); // {name: 'stackoverflow'} instead of {}
```

Comment: Because parameters are like local variables.

Comment: @Pointy 
Is it okay to understand it in this way?
`function changeEntireObj(objectY) {
   var localObjectY = objectY; // this is done under the hood
   localObject = {}; // memory address of original objectY is unchanged. 
}`

Comment: Yes, correct. Note that the fact that your parameter `objectY` has the same name is part of the story. The same code with a *different* name would behave the same way, but `function changeEntireObj(x) { objectY = {}; }` would behave as you expected, because in that case `objectY` *would* be a reference to the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Think of variable names (for objects) as containing the memory addresses for those objects. In case 1, the `objectX.name = 'google';` looks up the object in memory referenced by `objectX` and mutates one of its properties. In case 2, when you do `objectY = {};`, the variable referred to as `objectY` inside of that function will refer to the newly created empty object - but the original object defined outside the function was never reassigned, so it still points to the location in meory of the original object.

If you wanted the outer `objectY` to point to the new object, you'd have to explicitly return the new object from the function and reassign the outer variable:

```js
var objectY = {name: 'stackoverflow'};

function changeEntireObj(objectY) {
   objectY = {};
   return objectY;
}

objectY = changeEntireObj(objectY);
console.log(objectY);
```

Comment: Is it okay to understand it in this way?
`function changeEntireObj(objectY) {
   var localObjectY = objectY; // this is done under the hood
   localObject = {}; // memory address of original objectY is unchanged. 
}`

Comment: Sure, that's one way of looking at it - you're only changing the memory address of the local variable name, not of the outer variable name

Answer (score 0):

> passed by value, where the value is the memory address of the object

That's precisely what happens.

On entry of your `changeEntireObj(obj)` first argument contains address of object in JS heap.

And when you do

```
objectY = {};
```

you simply assign new value (address of new object) to the `objectY`.

This changes are local to the function. As parameters are passed by value new value of `objectY` will not be propagated outside of the function.